# ERROR: function avg(boolean) does not exist (MySql > PostgreSQL conversion)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following query which works great in MariaDB:

```
SELECT  floor(datediff(r.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago,
        date(min(r.created_at)) AS "Date Start",
        date(max(r.created_at)) AS "Date End",
        count(*) as  "Reviews in Cohort",
        AVG(has_note) as "Reviews w 1 or more Notes Ratio"
FROM (SELECT r.id, r.created_at,
             ( MAX(rn.note) IS NOT NULL ) as has_note
      FROM reviews f JOIN
           reviewss_notes rn
           ON r.id = rn.review_id

            WHERE r.completed_at IS NOT NULL
                    AND r.created_at > '2019-01-01'
                    AND r.type = "long_form"

            GROUP BY r.id
     ) f
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC;
```

I'm working to update the query to work in PostgreSQL. Here's my latest attempt:

```
SELECT  TRUNC(DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_DATE - r.created_at )/7)  AS weeks_ago,
        date(min(r.created_at)) AS "Date Start",
        date(max(r.created_at)) AS "Date End",
        count(*) as  "Reviews in Cohort",
        AVG(has_note) as "Reviews w 1 or more Notes Ratio"
FROM (SELECT r.id, r.created_at,
             ( MAX(rn.note) IS NOT NULL ) as has_note
      FROM reviews f JOIN
           reviewss_notes rn
           ON r.id = rn.review_id

            WHERE r.completed_at IS NOT NULL
                    AND r.created_at > '2019-01-01'
                    AND r.type = "long_form"

            GROUP BY r.id
     ) f
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC;
```

The error I'm getting from PostgreSQL is:

```
ERROR:  function avg(boolean) does not exist
LINE 5:         AVG(has_note) as "Reviews w 1 or more Notes Ratio"
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types.
```

Any ideas? Does PostgreSQL not allow this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert to a number:

```
    AVG(has_note::int) as "Reviews w 1 or more Notes Ratio"
```